# Construction of an operator on $\ell^2$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, examples-counterexamples

Let $E = \ell^2$ and $T$ the following operator
$$(T x)_n = b_n \, x_n$$
for a sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$.

> I want to choose $(b_n)_{n \in \mathbb N}$ such that
>
> - $T$ is bounded and positive-definite operator (i.e. $\langle Tx, x\rangle > 0$ for all $x \ne 0$).
> - $T$ has a closed range but not surjective.

If we take $T : \ell^2 \to \ell^2$ such that:

$$T(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = \left(x_1, \frac12 x_2, \frac13 x_3, \ldots\right),$$
we have $T$ is positive-definite operator. But I think that the range of $T$ is not closed.

Also I think that any positive bijective operator satisfies the above conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such sequence $(b_n)$. First note that $\langle Tx , x \rangle >0$ for $x \neq 0$ implies that $b_n >0$ for all $n$. Now suppose $(c_n)$ is orthogonal to the range of $T$. Then $\sum b_nx_nc_n=0$ for all $(x_n)$. This implies that $b_nc_n=0$ for all $n$ and hence $y_n=0$ for all $n$. Thus the range of $T$ is dense . If it is closed it has to be $\ell^{2}$.

Comment: Thank you so much. So, the only situation is that $T$ is bijective? I think my example $$T(x_1, x_2, x_3, \ldots) = \left(x_1, \frac12 x_2, \frac13 x_3, \ldots\right),$$ is correct. Here $T$ is bijective. Please correct me if I made wrong.

Comment: That is  not correct. In your example note that $(\frac  1n)$ is not in the range of $T$ (since we cannot have $x_n=1$ for all $n$). So the range of $T$ is a proper non-closed suspace in this case. The range is $\{(y_n): \sum n^{2}y_n^{2} <\infty\}$.  @Student

Comment: Yes you has right. Is there an example of such $T$ which satisfies the conditions? I think we should find $b_n$ such that $T$ is bijective. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Of course $b_n$ is not $1$ for all $n$.

Comment: @Student if $(b_n)$ is any sequence such that $b_n$ and $\frac 1 {b_n}$ are both bounded then  $T$ is bijective. For example you can take the sequence $(1,2,1,2,1,2...)$.